# I am not able to access my css and js file in public to my index.hbs in views folder

Tags: node.js, express, view, backend, hsb

I am trying to access css and js file which is in public folder from index.hbs which is inside views folder.

index.js file:

```
        const express = require('express')
        const path = require('path')
        // const hbs = require('hbs')
        const app = express()
        const port = 3000

        // const stat = path.join(__dirname, '../public')

        // app.use(express.static(stat))
        app.set('view engine' ,'hbs');
        app.set('/' ,path.join(__dirname, '/views'));


         app.get('/', (req, res) => {
          res.render('index', {})
          })
          app.get('/', (req, res) => {
          res.send("Hello")
          })

         app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
        })
```

LINK of css and JS in index.hsb:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
```

Folder structure

[image]

Comment: You need to use `express.static` middleware like  `app.use(express.static('public'))` where `public` is folder name

Comment: You may like to go through documentation https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **1. Add this middleware in the `index.js` above you set view engine**

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

### **2. Folder Structure**

```
|__public/   
    |__ css/
        |__ css files...
    |__ js/
        |__ js files...
```

**3. Import this way**

Now you set the path to the public directory you have to give the path public folder when you import

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
```

## **You should now be all set up to access css or any file**